# Combine and display blog post result combined with custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a custom blog page where I am able to list all posts. I have taxonomy post type named news and I want to display post available under this taxonomy mixed with normal posts on same page.

This is my while loop I am using to display post:

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

```
    <div class="columns large-12" style="margin-top:10px; border:1px solid #8080804a; padding-left: 0px;" id="2663539596">
    <div class="columns large-6" id="imagesection" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <p style="background-color: white; padding: 23px; color: black; position: absolute; z-index: 2; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 75px;"><?php echo get_the_date('jS \of F Y' ); ?> </p>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="columns large-6" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;">
        <p id="postcat" style="color:white; margin-top:100px; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif;"> <?php $id = $post->ID; echo esc_html(get_the_category( $id )[0]->name); ?> </p>
    <h2 id="posttitle" style="margin-top:70px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" style="color: white; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

" title="Read More" style="color: white; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, sans-serif; margin-left:5px; font-weight:bold"> Read More

so is there any method using which I can combine taxonomy result too with this.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve. If all of your posts are visible wouldn't the taxonomy posts already be in the mix of all the others?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a custom query. You can achieve this with [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

At your case, you need to create a query with two custom post types (POST and NEWS). Here is the sample code:

```
$custom_taxonomy = 'your_taxonomy_slug'; // UPDATE to your custom taxonomy slug
$cusom_taxonomy_terms = array( 'term_slug' ); // UPDATE to your custom taxonomy terms
$cpt_slug = 'news'; // UPDATE to your custom post type slug
// set the args for the Query
$args = array(
'post_type' => ['post','news'],
'tax_query' => [
    [
        'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $custom_taxonomy_terms,
    ]
 ]
);

// Create the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  // Loop start
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    // UPDATE pasting the loop code below
  }
  // End loop
} else {
 // No posts found
}

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```